# Can we be more specific with BurstFilter than all WARN lines?

Tags: logging, log4j2

We'd like to use a [BurstFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#BurstFilter) setting that will rate limit mass logging when something upstream breaks. However, our concern is that if we use something like `<BurstFilter level="WARN" rate="10" maxBurst="100"/>`, we'll inadvertently filter out less spammy `WARN` lines that we'd actually like to action on.

Is there a way we could apply a rate limit that matches the rate of a specific class (or something similar) so that we don't throw away good logs?

I was thinking something along:

```
  <Filters>
    <RegexFilter regex=".* our.custom.class.ServiceImpl .*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    <BurstFilter level="WARN" rate="10" maxBurst="100"/>
  </Filters>
```

But I'm pretty sure that would just ignore everything that doesn't match our pattern, and rate limit what does.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you have your loggers configured, but you could use the hierarchical nature of loggers to filter WARN level messages by class or package.

Here's a simple example to illustrate:

First, the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <BurstFilter level="WARN" rate="1" maxBurst="5" />
        </Console>
        <Console name="Console-NoFilter" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>


    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-NoFilter" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="example.OtherClass" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-NoFilter" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="example.SomeClass" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now the first java class:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
            log.warn("spam warning "+i);
        }

        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
        other.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Here's a second java class:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class OtherClass {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void doStuff(){
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
            log.warn("not so spam warning "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

When `SomeClass` is run it will generate only 5 WARN messages in the console, whereas `OtherClass` generates 20 WARN messages since it has no filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to a specific Logger

> Logger Filters are configured on a specified Logger. These are evaluated after the Context-wide Filters and the Log Level for the Logger.

~ [Log4j Filters](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html)

```xml
<Logger name="com.example.SomeClass" level="INFO">
    <BurstFilter level="WARN" rate="10" maxBurst="20" />
</Logger>
```